# How to register IHubContext in a dependency container like SimpleInjector for web api in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

my project is built on Asp.Net Core and is using `SimpleInjectorWebApiInitialer` for registering dependencies and while injecting those dependencies, it reads it's corresponding implementation registered.
Example:

```
var container = new Container()
container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

In my case, I am injecting `IHubContext` in my classes to call client methods but while initializing the classes, it throws an exception to register `IHubContext`. So, how should we register it in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .NET Core, `SignalR` is already native for it. So you don't need to inject it to the service. Using `app.UseSignalR` on Configure and `services.AddSignalR()` on ConfigureServices already do what you want. Then you just need to call the dependency in your managers like `IHubContext<YourHubHub, IYourHub>`.